# Compiling PySide resources through python

Tags: python, resources, pyside

I want to write a script to compile a bunch of PySide qrc files, but I can't find a PySide library to do it.  I know I can just call pyside-rcc using `subprocess`, but I would prefer to do it directly through python.  Does anyone know how, or if, this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the answer is no. pyrcc is written in C++ (even though pyuic is written in Python).

http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-tools/trees/master/pyrcc